# Zoom in for MS SQL Server Database Connection screen

Tags: sql-server

Problem:

When try to connect to SQL database, the SQL server database connection screen/page is too small to read. Is there any way to zoom in and make the form bigger?

[image]

Comment: Would the [Magnifier](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-magnifier-to-make-things-on-the-screen-easier-to-see-414948ba-8b1c-d3bd-8615-0e5e32204198#ID0EBBF=Windows_10) accessibility tool work?

Comment: that is a good temp workaround. though not ideal, as I RDP to a server, a bit inconvenience to navigate around

Answer (score 2):

Update the SSMS to v18 or above. Should resolve your issue.

[SQL Server Management Studio 18 New Features - High DPI Support and 2 MB Query Output to Minimize Truncated Results](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6126/sql-server-management-studio-18-new-features-high-dpi-support-and-2-mb-query-output-to-minimize-truncated-results/)